# ABMultiValueIdentifier was not set correctly in ABPeoplePickerNavigationControllerDelegate, an iOS bug?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, addressbook, abaddressbook

I hit this weird problem when implementing ABPeoplePickerNavigationControllerDelegate. So identifier sometime was got its value incorrectly in delegate method

```
- (BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person property:(ABPropertyID)property identifier:(ABMultiValueIdentifier)identifier;
```

For example when I chose the first number from a contact, identifier should be 0. But sometime it was 1 (even when that contact only has 1 number)!!

It is easy to verify that,

```
...
ABMultiValueRef phoneProperty = ABRecordCopyValue(person,property);
int count = ABMultiValueGetCount(phoneProperty);
NSLog(@"How many numbers do I have %d and which number do I choose %d",count,identifier);
```

And it printed out this sometime

> How many numbers do I have **1** and which number do I choose **1**

so has anyone hit the same problem as well ?

Update: sometime identifier is even bigger than count. How come!!

> How many numbers do I have 2 and which number do I choose 3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just figured out why and feel embarrassed of myself.

So ABMultiValueIdentifier is different than index, after I got identifier I need to use ABMultiValueGetIndexForIdentifier to get the index. Then using that index to call ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex.

BTW, there was a same question at [AdressBook Crash, only with some contacts!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3818360/adressbook-crash-only-with-some-contacts)